# Getting a range from a range in Google Apps scripting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to get a subrange from a range?

ie.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var fullRange = ss.getRange("A:P");
```

Can I get a range from `fullRange`?

The context is that I'm using data validation to dynamically set a data validation dropdown based on a range.

Example: I have two cells - the first one is a dropdown with a list of categories, and the second is a dropdown with a list of subcategories thats dependent on the category selected in the first cell.

The way I'm making this happen is based on the category selection, I populate a hidden row with the list of subcategories based on that category selection. Then I use `requireValueInRange` to set the data validation for that subcategory cell.

It works fine, except runs SUPER slow, and I'm trying to figure out a way to make it faster. I'm guessing one of the reasons its slow is because I'm using `getRange` in a loop to get the proper `requireValueInRange`. So I'm trying to pull a subrange instead of re-querying the range every time.

```
function setDataValidations() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var categoryRange = ss.getRange("A:A");
  var subCatCells = ss.getRange("B:B");

  var subCatRules = subCatCells.getDataValidations();

  var rangeLength = categoryRange.getValues().length;

  for (var i = 1; i < rangeLength; i++ ){
    var catCell = categoryRange.getCell(i, 1);
    var subCatOptions = ss.getRange("'subcats'!A" + i + ":P" + i);
    var subCatRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(subCatOptions, true).build();
  }
  catCells.setDataValidations(subCatRules);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Range#getCell`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell(Integer,Integer)) is how one references a `Range` from within an existing `Range`, so you're already doing what you're asking to do. As you note, using [`Range#setDataValidations`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationsrules) is superior to cell-by-cell setting, as it is a batch method. Given that you use the [`requireValueInRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInRange(Range,Boolean)) validation rule, there is no way to avoid acquiring additional `Range`s.

However, acquiring them can be done more effectively, for specific use cases where there is a well-defined relationship, through the use of [`RangeList`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)s. A `RangeList` is a batch-acquired `Range`, generally intended for uses where disjoint Ranges are to be treated equivalently.

```
function setDVs() {
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const catSheetName = "the name of the sheet that has the dropdowns",
      sheet = wb.getSheetByName(catSheetName),
      maxDVs = sheet.getLastRow();

  // Create the A1-notation or R1C1-notation Arrays identifying the ranges we need.
  const subCatNotations = [];
  const subCatSheetName = "the name of the sheet that has the ranges with required values"
  for (var r = 1; r <= maxDVs; ++r)
    subCatNotations.push("A" + r + ":P" + r); // 1 row, cols A:P

  // Range#setDataValidations requires an Array of Array of DataValidations.
  // Thus, wrap the new rule in a new array if updating a single column.
  const new_dvs = wb.getSheetByName(subCatSheetName)
      .getRangeList(subCatNotations).getRanges()
      .map(function (subCatRange) {
        return [
          SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(subCatRange, true).build()
        ];
      });

  // Batch-apply the new rules to the `catSheetName` sheet.
  if (new_dvs.length && new_dvs[0].length)
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, new_dvs.length, new_dvs[0].length).setDataValidations(new_dvs); // col A
}
```

References

- [`RangeList`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)
- [`setDataValidations`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationsrules)
- [`requireValueInRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInRange(Range,Boolean))
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: using `RangeList`s did the trick...went from 5 min for ~300 rows to 1min for 5000 rows. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

the example below alows to get a subRange made of all rows and only some columns.

```
function getRangeByCols( myRange,  fromCol,  toCol){
  firstRowIndex = myRange.getRow()
  firstColIndex = myRange.getColumn()
  rowsNumber = myRange.getHeight()
  colsNumber = myRange.getWidth()

  return myRange.getSheet().getRange(firstRowIndex,firstColIndex+fromCol-1,rowsNumber,toCol-fromCol+1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple function that fills a given `Range` with data, according to the size of the data:

```js
/**
 * Fills a range with the data provided (2D Array)
 * regardless of the number of rows/columns in the 
 * data
 **/
function fillRange(range, data) {
  range.clear({contentsOnly: true}) // Optional

  const target = range.getSheet().getRange(
    range.getRow(), range.getColumn(), 
    data.length, data[0].length)
  target.setValues(data)
}
```